# Read message length without deserializing protobuf composite stream

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I have a `Stream` that contains several messages. I have used `SerializeWithLengthPrefix` to save these messages.

I need to make an index map to find the byte offset for the *nth* message, such that I can do this:

```
public object Read(int index)
{
    object deserialized;

    _stream.Seek( _map[index], SeekOrigin.Begin);

    ProtoBuf.Serializer.NonGeneric.TryDeserializeWithLengthPrefix(
        _stream,
        ProtoBuf.PrefixStyle.Base128,
        _typeResolver,
        out deserialized
        );

    return deserialized;
}
```

where `_map` is the unknown.

Currently, my solution to finding the map is going to be entirely deserializing the messages.

So I have two questions;

Can I bounce off the length prefixes and find all the start (byte offsets) locations for each message without deserializing the entire message steam?

Is it likely simply deserializing the messages entirely and tracking the changes in the stream position will be faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using a base-128 prefix, you can probably simply use `Serializer.TryReadLengthPrefix` twice per message. The first time returns the field header - the second is the length. Then skip forward that-many bytes to the next message.

Comment: yes that worked - skip first byte, second is byte length. Cheers.

Comment: @MeirionHughes warning: varints; not bytes. If you treat them as bytes, it will fail for anything over 127. `TryReadLengthPrefix` reads varints.